# Having trouble with grouping in 3D Studio Max

Tags: 3dsmax

I'm using 3D Studio Max 2012. I've got a simple mesh and several other polygons and I want to group everything all together. But the option is greyed out, I can't actually select 'Group' under the menus.

I've tried exploding and collapsing the mesh but nothing seems to work.

How can I group them together, what things can I do to try to diagnose the problem?

EDIT:
My object hierarchy looks weird:

```
scene root:
 . object 1
model:
 - object 2 ... 99
```

Comment: I fixed the problem by moving everything under `model`. I guess everything needs to be under the same parent to group.

Comment: You should post that as an answer so that the question can be marked as accepted by the system.

Comment: I couldn't post a reply to the answer at the time, the option wasn't available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3D Studio Max has issues when trying to group objects with different parents. In a way, it makes sense that objects with different hierarchies shouldn't be allowed to group together. However, from an unwary user's perspective, this is a frustrating, wtf, kind of "gotcha".

To fix it, simply correct the hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

select the objects you want to group. hit the unlink selection button (the broken chain icon) And than you can group.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another workaround if you are in a rush, just highlight all the objects and create a 'selection set' this helps enough for me. Of course it depends what you intend to use them for once they are grouped...